# Full Page Cache - Hole punch for timestamp

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, block-cache, holepunching

Many of my templates require a timestamp (for timers), when implementing full page cache (using [nitrogento](http://www.nitrogento.com/)) the timestamp gets cached too which ends up showing wrong timestamp.

What methods can I employ to still keep most of my page cached yet hole punch the timestamp part

Comment: This is still one of my favorite resources for hole punching and the example extension in this article is very similar to what you are attempting. http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/03/overcoming-magentos-full-page-cache-through-hole-punching/